# Librerias de Office en Visual Studio para Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio, macos

Buenos Días:
  Hace unos días en el trabajo nos trajeron un Mac Mini para migrar algunos proyectos realizados para Windows a Mac.
  El problema me ha venido cuando al instalar Visual Studio para Mac y compilar mi programa me ha dado un error en la libreria de Microsoft.Office.interop.Word, la cual utilizo para poder trabajar con ficheros de Word desde mi programa.
  Mi pregunta es que librerias hay para poder seguir gestionando documentos word desde mi proyecto pero en mac. 
  Si no hay para trabajar con word podria cambiar el documento a otro editor de texto que fuera parecido, y que si se pueda mandar una instruccion desde visual studio para abrirlo. 
  Trabajo en codigo C#.
  Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ahora mismo el soporte multiplataforma de .net (net.core) está todavia en pañales, con lo que es dificil encontrar librerias que te ayuden. De todas maneras, echa un vistazo [aqui (Open XML SDK)](https://github.com/xrkolovos/Open-XML-SDK-for-NET-Platform-Standard),es posible que te sirva de punto de partida

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Si que me ha servido.

Comment: De nada. Me alegro que te haya ayudado :)

Comment: Hola Buenas Tardes @Pikoh: Una vez que ya e modificado el word necesitaría pasarlo a PDF, conoces alguna librería o como lo podría hacer desde esa misma librería. Gracias de Antemano

Comment: No,lo siento @Maria, desde esa libería creo que no es posible y no conozco otra que pueda hacerlo. Una posible solución sería crear algun servicio web en algun servidor que realice esa conversión, aunque si la aplicación va a ser distribuida a clientes esta opcion no es muy factible. De todas maneras te recomiendo que hagas otra pregunta por si alguien sabe algo mas y te puede ayudar. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

He utilizado Visual Studio para mac y es muy limitado la verdad, incluso en el package he podido encontrar muy poco, esta mas enfocado a lo q es mobile, tuve q instalar una maquina virtual con windows para poder seguir trabajando en la mac, hago algunas cosas con ese visual studio pero yo lo vi mas como un Xamarin q un Visual Studio